# How pass attributes by using <f:attribute> inside declarative component in Oracle ADF?

Tags: oracle-adf

I have a declarative component in which the component ui is generated at run time based on the parameters passed to the tag.

as you can see I have a string value in #{attrs.innerObject}

```html
<af:panelGroupLayout id="dc_pgl1" layout="horizontal">
<af:inputText id="date_input" value="#{attrs.value}" maximumLength="10" 
                contentStyle="width:#{attrs.width}px; text-align:center;" immediate="true" autoSubmit="true"  
                valueChangeListener="#{component.handleValueChangeListener}">
    <f:attribute name="innerObject" value="#{attrs.innerObject}"/>
</af:inputText>

<af:image id="date_btn" source="/images/calendar1.png" >
    <af:clientListener method="executeSelection" type="mouseOver"/>
</af:image>
```

After creating Adf jar library and adding that jar to the project I use this declarative component like the following:

```html
<isc:persianCalendar value="1393/12/01" width="150" valueChangeListener="#{test.xyz}" innerObject="123"/>
```

But the attribute map doesn't contain the innerObject.

```js
public void xyz(ValueChangeEvent valueChangeEvent) {
    Object innerObject = (Object) valueChangeEvent.getComponent().getAttributes().get("innerObject");
    System.out.println("innerObject : "+ innerObject);}
```

Is there anything wrong on this approach? What is the recommended way to solve this problem?
Would be nice if someone could help us out.

Comment: It looks okey to me, except immediate="true" attribute which doesn't make sense on my opinion.

Here you can find few more details on how Immediate=true works with input Text: http://adfpractice-fedor.blogspot.co.uk/2012/02/understanding-immediate-attribute.html

Comment: I eliminated the immediate="true" but still the bug exist.

Comment: Can you try changing the value directly inside input field without using the image link, and check what value you get for:

valueChangeEvent.geComponent().getId()

Then, try changing the value from the image, see if there is any difference.
It depends on what your javascript method executeSelection does, I supose.

Comment: What class of this component `valueChangeEvent.getComponent()`. I suspect u getting your custom component instead of inputText

Comment: Thank you so much for your kindly response.
But it is not a javascript matter. 
Let me to ask my question with another scenario for clarification.
--As you know we can pass attributes from jsp pages to managed beans using <f:attribute> inside any jsf component. 
--Now how I can use this feature when I am creating and using my own JSF declarative component?
Best Regards.

Comment: Amir, to answer your question: yes, you can. I used myself such scenario before.

Comment: Is it possible to share  the solution?